# Metamask is not showing the balance

Tags: metamask, rinkeby, nft

I use rinkeby faucet to get some ether, when I check the Etherscan it successfully deposit to my account(0x0E2a77b).

I have two question to ask.

**First question is**, When I go to Metamask it doesn't show the balance, how can I solve it?

**Second question is**, I'm using the opensea marketplace, I successfully to connect to my metamask, but when I trying to buy some NFT, the metamask doesn't pop out, I'm not sure that I missed setting something in metamask or it is because I have no balance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I reinstall Metamask and import the mnemonic phrase**, the balance has shown successfully and I can also successfully buy NFT on opensea marketplace.